# Google guice, override configuration

Tags: dependency-injection, playframework, guice

I'm working with Guice and have one design question. My App consists of few module:

- myapp-persistence (JPA Entities, DAO, other DB related stuff)
- myapp-backend (Some background daemons, they use myapp-persistence )
- myapp-rest (REST app that depends on myapp-persistence)

myapp-persistence must have singleton HibernateSessionFactory. It's by Hibernate design. 
No problem I can solve it with Guice:

```
class MyAppPersistenceModule extends AbstractModule {

  override def configure(): Unit = {

    bind(classOf[SomeStuff])
    bind(classOf[ClientDao])
    bind(classOf[CustomerDao])
    bind(classOf[SessionFactory]).toProvider(classOf[HibernateSessionFactoryProvider]).asEagerSingleton()

  }

  @Provides
  def provideDatabaseConnectionConfiguration: DatabaseConnectionConfiguration = {
    DatabaseConnectionConfiguration.fromSysEnv
  }

}
```

The problem with passing **DatabaseConnectionConfiguration** to that singleton. myapp-persistence module doesn't really care how to get that config. Right now it's taken from sys variables.

myapp-rest is play-app and it wants to read conf from application.conf and inject it into other components using Guice.
myapp-backend does more or less the same.

Right now I'm locked myself with

```
@Provides
  def provideDatabaseConnectionConfiguration: DatabaseConnectionConfiguration = {
    DatabaseConnectionConfiguration.fromSysEnv
  }
```

And I don't understand how to make it flexible and configurable for myapp-rest and myapp-backend.

**UPD**
According to answer, I did it this way:

Defined trait

```
trait DbConfProvider {
  def dbConf: DbConf
}
```

Singleton factory now depends on provider:

```
class HibernateSessionFactoryProvider @Inject()(dbConfProvider: DbConfProvider) extends Provider[SessionFactory] {
}
```

myapp-persistence module exposes public guice module with all piblic persistence module DAO.

myapp-persistence has module used only for testing purposes. myapp-persistence Injector load module described below:

```
class MyAppPersistenceDbConfModule extends AbstractModule {

  override def configure(): Unit = {
    bind(classOf[DbConfProvider]).to(classOf[DbConfSysEnvProvider])
  }

}
```

DbConfSysEnvProvider reads DB connection settings from sys env. Non production use case.

Play app has it's own conf mechanism. I've added my custom module to app conf:

```
# play-specific config
play.modules.enabled += "common.components.MyAppPersistenceDbConfModule"
# public components from myapp-persistence module.
play.modules.enabled += "com.myapp.persistence.connection.PersistenceModule"
```

And my configuration service:

```
@Singleton
class ConfigurationService @Inject()(configuration: Configuration) extends DbConfProvider {
...}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not an expert on Play-specific setup, but generally this kind of design problem is solved in one of the following ways:

1. No default. Remove the binding of DatabaseConnectionConfiguration from the upstream module (myapp-persistence), and define it in each downstream module (myapp-backend, myapp-rest) as appropriate.
2. Default with override. Keep the default binding of DatabaseConnectionConfiguration like you did, implementing the most common configuration strategy there. Override it in downstream modules using [Guice Modules.override(..)](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/util/Modules.html#override-com.google.inject.Module...-) API when needed.
3. Implement a unified configuration mechanism across the modules, that does not depend on particular frameworks used. (E.g. [Bootique](https://github.com/bootique/bootique), which is built on Guice ... Haven't used it with Play though).

I personally prefer the approach #3, but in the absence of something like Bootique, #2 is a good substitute.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas!